# Why do I get b' at the start of each line and ' at the end of each line?

Tags: python, pxssh

I have this python script that uses pxssh.  Here's the script:

```
from pexpect import pxssh
import getpass
try:
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = input('hostname: ')
    username = input('username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    s.login(hostname, username, password)
    s.sendline('cat hiera/my.yaml')   # run a command
    s.prompt()             # match the prompt
    for line in s.before.splitlines()[1:]:
       print (line)
    s.logout()
except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh as e:
    print("pxssh failed on login.")
    print(e)
```

and I cannot understand why the script output looks like this:

```
b'---'
b'settings_prod: |'
b'"""'
b"Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.5."
b''
b'For more information on this file, see'
b'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/'
b''
b'For the full list of settings and their values, see'
b'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/'
b'"""'
```

What is up with the `b'` at the start of each line and the `'` on the end of each line of output? How do I get rid if it?

Comment: It's binary data right?  Is this Python3?  try `print( str( line, 'utf-8' ) )`

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's binary data, it needs to be converted with `str()`.

```
print( str( line, 'utf-8' ) )
```

There's a bunch of other string formats, like `iso-8859-1`, `iso-8859-16`, etc.
But, if in doubt, try `utf-8` first.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an
>   instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals